# NSLog output not showing in XCode 5.0.2

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5, osx-mavericks

Im am using `XCode 5.0.2` on `OSX Mavericks`.I have a `NSLog` in my code whenever a button is pressed. But output from `NSLog` does not show up in the output window. I have "All Messages" selected.I have attached a screenshot of my screen.

How can i fix this ?

Thank You

```
//
//  RSViewController.m
//  CoffeeApp
//
//  Created by Raza Sayed on 18/01/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Raza Sayed. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RSViewController.h"

@interface RSViewController ()

@end

@implementation RSViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)calculateButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Calculate Button Pressed");
}
@end
```

[image]

Comment: Set a breakpoint in calculateButtonPressed at first to convince that it fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have seemingly a binding issue with your button.

Check in Interface Builder/Storyboard that the button is bound to the `calculateButtonPressed` action method. For this: go to the button in IB, click on it, then in the Utilities pane go to Connection Inspector (or shortly press cmd-opt-6).

Comment: Thanks that was indeed the problem ! :)